# What you call the action of when someone does not do something for you quickly?

Tags: single-word-requests

They give you a lot of excuses for not doing it but never actually say they won't do it.

Comment: Asian  ...j/k

Answer (score 9):

**[Stalling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stall)** could work here:

> to delay, especially by evasion or deception.
>
> I asked him to do it, but he keeps stalling.

To *[procrastinate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/procrastinate)* means to *put off*, so it could work, too, in some circumstances.

There are many other synonyms, each with different nuances of meaning.  [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/stalling) presents many choices.

Answer (score 5):

*Dragging one's feet* is another such phrase.

Answer (score 2):

[**Hemming and hawing**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hem--2?region=us&rskey=hC0fVX&result=2):

> **hem and haw** hesitate; be indecisive : *I waste a lot of time hemming and hawing before going into action*.
>
> ORIGIN late 15th cent.: imitative.

Comment: Interesting. Is this common in the UK? I've never heard it in the US (west coast)...

Comment: @tjameson: Not sure about the UK, but I'm familiar with it over on this coast.

Answer (score 1):

**Temporize** would work.  The OED defines it thus:

†2. intr. To let time pass, spend time, ‘mark time’; to procrastinate; to delay or wait for a more favourable moment.

Answer (score 1):

[Dawdling](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dawdle) could be appropriate here, especially sense (2): to move lackadaisically

Comment: But that doesn't imply that someone isn't following through on a promise. I think of someone dawdling if they're wasting their own time

Answer (score 1):

I would call the action of someone not doing something for me quickly, simply *delay*.   But if, over time, lots of excuses are given for not doing it, but "Not going to happen" is never said, I would call that *being strung along*, or being *taken for a fool*, or *messing with my head*, depending on what motives I attribute the delay to.
(The previously-mentioned *stalling*, *temporizing*,  and *foot-dragging* are other terms I might use, but my primary choice is *being strung along* or *stringing me along*.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably call it [**inaction.**](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=pfwc&cp=7&gs_id=q&xhr=t&q=inaction&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&site=&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=inactio&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=f&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=fc1f175dc4ba964c&biw=1024&bih=581)

Answer (score -1):

Not to put too fine a point on it, pain in the arse.